# How to test elements on canvas in android through Robotium

Tags: android, user-interface, canvas, robotium

I am trying to test elements on the canvas with Robotium but it is not working correctly.

I am using the `SearchText()` function to find the written text on the screen (canvas) but it's not working.

Is there any other way to test whether that string is present on the screen (canvas)?

Comment: Please show us the code you are using

Comment: Code of android activity?

Comment: Canvas c;
c.drawText(messageScoreCurrent+score, (getWidth()/100)*10, (getHeight()/100)*10, paint);

I want to test whether score is being displayed on screen

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know robotium alone cannot help you here sadly, it can only understand android views which elements on a canvas are not.

You can use opencv via android to do this but it is not trivial...